# docker pull using proxy gives "first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Tags: ssl, docker, proxy

I have corporate server that must use proxy for outbound traffic. Following the Microsoft's docker documentation, I've run Powershell commands:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://my.secret.proxy.net:8888", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "https://my.secret.proxy.net:8888", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
Restart-Service docker
```

but running a `docker build` after that gives me:

```
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I've tried using `http` instead `https` for the proxy addresses etc. Same results. The proxy is transparent proxy and does nothing "smart".

Running `pip install flake8 --proxy=https://my.secret.proxy.net:8888` works so I know the proxy works.

Any ideas? Any tips to debug further? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `"HTTPS_PROXY", "https://my.secret.proxy.net:8888"` change `https://` to `http://`

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of docker for windows, there is a [resources -> proxies](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#general) section of the UI where you configure proxies to use for pulling images.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

You'll still need to configure proxy variables in running containers. For this you can update the `~/.docker/config.json` with:

```json
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}
```

I'm not positive where this is located on windows, particularly if you're not using WSL2, but the file should already exist if you've done a `docker login` to login to a registry.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/